# Dificoulties installing gloss and other packages with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, modulenotfounderror, gloss

I am trying to install gloss but, I dont know why ghci doesn't find the modules.

When I do cabal install gloss it says:

```
Up to date
Warning: You asked to install executables, but there are no executables in
target: gloss. Perhaps you want to use --lib to install libraries instead.
```

When I do cabal install -lib gloss it gives me thies error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: bytestring-0.11.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: directory (user goal)
[__1] rejecting: directory-1.3.6.1 (constraint from user target requires
==1.3.6.0)
[__1] trying: directory-1.3.6.0/installed-1.3.6.0
[__2] next goal: Win32 (dependency of directory)
[__2] rejecting: Win32-2.6.1.0/installed-2.6.1.0 (conflict:
bytestring==0.11.0.0, Win32 => bytestring==0.10.10.0/installed-0.10.10.0)
[__2] rejecting: Win32-2.10.1.0, Win32-2.10.0.0, Win32-2.9.0.0, Win32-2.8.5.0,
Win32-2.8.4.0, Win32-2.8.3.0, Win32-2.8.2.0, Win32-2.8.1.0, Win32-2.8.0.0,
Win32-2.7.0.0, Win32-2.6.2.0, Win32-2.6.1.0, Win32-2.6.0.0, Win32-2.5.4.1,
Win32-2.5.3.0, Win32-2.5.2.0, Win32-2.5.1.0, Win32-2.5.0.0, Win32-2.4.0.0,
Win32-2.3.1.1, Win32-2.3.1.0, Win32-2.3.0.2, Win32-2.3.0.1, Win32-2.3.0.0,
Win32-2.2.2.0, Win32-2.2.1.0, Win32-2.2.0.2, Win32-2.2.0.1, Win32-2.2.0.0,
Win32-2.1.0.0, Win32-2.1, Win32-2.5.4.0 (conflict: directory =>
Win32==2.6.1.0/installed-2.6.1.0)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: Win32, bytestring, directory)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: ghc, bytestring, Win32, directory
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

This is very strange because the firs time I used this command it worked perfectly but then when I tried to do on ghci ´´´import ...´´´ it sayd: Module not found.

I have tried other modules and it gives me the same error. I thought that the issue could be that ghc is not able to search in the cabal folder where the packages are saved but I am no longer sure.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: This question is too vague to be answerable in this form, and anyways there have been numerous very similar questions in the past that probably solve your issue. My recommendation: don't ever _install any packages_ at all. Instead, _depend_ on them in a local project, and then use `cabal repl` (or `stack ghci`), which automatically installs anything needed.

Comment: Hey thanks for your coment. The problem is that I don't know how to make it more specific since it is the only error I am getting. I haven't been able to find a question with a soluton that may solve my issue. Sorry for bothering all of you but I am relatively new to programing. When u say depend on them locally what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean you should create a small dummy cabal project (this can be created very quickly with `cabal init` in a new directory with just a single `.hs` file in it). Then, in the `PROJECTNAME.cabal` file, list the packages you need under `build-depends`, and you'll be able to import any of the modules in the `.hs` file. That file can then be loaded with `cabel repl`, which is just like `ghci` except that all the import you need are already taken care for.

Comment: Thanks a lot leftaroundabout!!! I'll definetly try that.